# Get objects from database with/without (number) Like copy number

Tags: c#, entity

I'm creating a "Folder" system for MVC. ( C# + Identity )

The user are able to create "folders" and if the same name match another folder it has to add (number) to the name.

Folders:

- Code
- Test
- Test (1)
- Code (1)
- Code (2)
- Test this site

Lets say a new user wants to add another folder called Test.

Basic I need to count how many "Folders" that Exist by the `exact name` or `Exact name + (number)`

```
int count = db.Folders.Where(i => i.Name == Name).ToList().Count
```

It should return (with the correct logic) `count = 2`. And then `create Test (2)`

I cant seem to figure out how to rework the code about so I counts the matches correctly according to the logic. Can someone point me in the right direction ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
db.Folders.Where(i => i.Name == Name).ToList().Count
```

will give you the matches where the name is exactly "Name".

I think you must query where name startswith "Name" and length = "Name" + space + bracket + number + bracket .

then you must make sure that you didn't get something like "Test (e)" but "Test (3)"

*Edit*

Note that you must get the names instead of just count because you may have a situation like :

- Test
- Test (1)
- Test (13)

and in this case your folder must be "Test (2)" instead "Test (4)" or "Test (14)"

Out there may be good algorithms for this but here is what I think now:

you get a list of names starting with your folder name:

```
var items = db.Folders.Where(i => i.Name.StartsWith(Name)).ToList();
```

then :

```
     string whatIWant = Name;
     for(int i=1;; i++)
     {
        whatIWant = Name + " (" + i.ToString() + ")";
        if(!items.Contains(whatIWant))
        {
            break;
        }
     }

// proceed with insert
```

Comment: Worked, but i had to change items.contains(whatIWant) with .ToList().Exists(x => x.Name == whatiwant)